# Node.js cannot publish module. getting error Invalid name 'math_example'

Tags: node.js

I have been trying to publish my module using the command prompt command 
npm publish. and am getting the below error. I am having an account on the npm website and am also logging before I before I publish.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your module is in conflict with something already present on the NPM site.

Change your module's name from `mathexampleTest` to something else and see if you get this error again.

### EDIT:

Modules can no longer have capital letters in their name.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7351

Comment: I have checked on the website. https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mathexampleTest . Its free available

Comment: There is a chance it's a Private module or just a reserved name, because this seems to be just a test you can name it anything random.

Comment: @Adi I have this same problem I'll up vote if you tell me how to find the package on my system... I'm not sure It even exists!

Comment: It appears `:` and `/` are invalid chars for a package name.